# Supabase - create view from web UI SQL editor fails with 'Invalid SQL'

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

From the Supabase admin web UI I'm trying to create a new view and this fails but all I get is am "invalid SQL" message

The DDL is...

```
CREATE VIEW gd_goal_task
AS
SELECT
  a."goalId", a."taskDefId", a."displayOrder", b.*
FROM public.gd_goal_task_link a 
LEFT JOIN public.gd_task b on a."taskDefId" = b."defId"
WITH (security_invoker = on) AS
select * from public.gd_goal_task
```

Any suggestions of how I can trace the problem to find out what's wrong?

The two tables are:

- "gd_goal_task_link" is a physical table
- "gd_task" is a logical view

I'm presuming that you can create logical views from other logical views

Answer (score 0):

Solved it...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.gd_goal_task
with (security_invoker = on)
AS
SELECT m."goalId", m."displayOrder", n.*
FROM public.gd_goal_task_link m 
inner join public.gd_task n on m."taskDefId" = n."defId"
```